# new PouchDB() promise returning too soon?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am connecting to a remote database and listening for changes, but want the ability to stop listening. PouchDB seems to have all of the functionality I need, but setting it up properly seems to be an issue. PouchDB's documentation has the simple example I'm following.

```
var changes = db.changes({
  since: 20,
  live: true
}).on('change', function(change) { });

changes.cancel();
```

In the following code I establish my remote database source, and once that has successfully completed I set up my listeners and save off my change listener so I can call cancel at some later point. The whole thing returns a promise so the rest of my app can know when we're ready to go.. db and changelistener are defined elsewhere in the app and accessible via "this.xxx" or "self.xxx" when the scope requires it.

```
SyncService.prototype.openDB = function(){
    console.log("open db");
    var self = this;

    var deferred = this.$q.defer();

    this.db = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/somedb")
    .then( function(){
        console.log("db source established");
        console.log( self.db );

        self.changeListener = self.db.changes({
            live: true,
            include_docs: true,
            since: "now"
        })
        .on('change', function( changes ){
            console.log( changes );
        })
        .on('error', function(err){
            console.log(err)
        });

        console.log( self.changeListener );

        deferred.resolve();

    }, function(err){
        console.log( err );
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When I run this, my database is created, but it seems that the promise of "new PouchDB" is executing prematurely. My console logs looks like this..

```
open db
db source established
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

... and that's it. The db promise seems to resolve, but appears to be pending in the console log.. and we never get past the code segment where we set up the listener. The deferred.resolve() is never executed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`self.db.changes` doesn't exists. `self.db` is pointing to a promise (your own call to `console.log(self.db)` shows that).

You must accept a `database` parameter on your success handler and then call the changes API with `database.changes(...)`.